# Why is the page.waitFor() button not responding in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I have been successfully developing some tests with Jest and Puppeteer and I had one major challenge and now I have run into another one.

I have a Send Survey button that is supposed to be clicked by `await page.click('button.green');` This should work because I ran that selector in the console: `$('button.green')
<button class=​"green btn-flat right white-text">​…​</button>​` and sure enough I got back the right element.

The `waitFor()` method should work with that selector as well, I tested it out: `$('.card')
<div class=​"card darken-1">​<div class=​"card-content">​…​</div>​<div class=​"card-action">​…​</div>​</div>​`

Anybody have any ideas what could be the reason why this particular test is failing?

```
describe("And using valid inputs", async () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await page.type("input[name=title]", "My Title");
      await page.type("input[name=subject]", "My Subject");
      await page.type("input[name=body]", "This is the body of the email");
      await page.type("input[name=recipients]", "example@gmail.com");
      await page.click("form button.teal");
    });

    test("Submitting takes user to review screen", async () => {
      const text = await page.getContentsOf("h5");

      expect(text).toEqual("Please confirm your entries");
    });

    test("Submitting then saving adds survey to index page", async () => {
      await page.click("button.green");
      await page.waitFor(".card");

      const title = await page.getContentsOf(".card-title");
      const content = await page.getContentsOf("p");

      expect(title).toEqual("My Title");
      expect(content).toEqual("This is the body of the email");
    });
  });
```

This is the error I get:

```
 FAIL  tests/surveys.test.js (46.311s)
  When logged in
    ✓ can see survey create form (4726ms)
    And using valid inputs
      ✓ Submitting takes user to review screen (4360ms)
      ✕ Submitting then saving adds survey to index page (33430ms)
    And using invalid inputs
      ✓ the form shows an error message (2966ms)

  ● When logged in › And using valid inputs › Submitting then saving adds survey to index page

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:68:21
      at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:678:19)

  ● When logged in › And using valid inputs › Submitting then saving adds survey to index page

    TimeoutError: waiting for selector ".card" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

      40 |     test("Submitting then saving adds survey to index page", async () => {
      41 |       await page.click("button.green");
    > 42 |       await page.waitFor(".card");
      43 |
      44 |       const title = await page.getContentsOf(".card-title");
      45 |       const content = await page.getContentsOf("p");

      at new WaitTask (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:554:28)
      at DOMWorld._waitForSelectorOrXPath (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:483:22)
      at DOMWorld.waitForSelector (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:437:17)
      at Frame.waitForSelector (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:608:47)
      at Frame.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
      at Frame.waitFor (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:593:19)
      at Proxy.waitFor (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:1064:29)
      at Object.waitFor (tests/surveys.test.js:42:18)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 6 passed, 7 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        47.365s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. It seems like there is no `.card` element appearing on the page. Without seeing the actual page, I doubt anyone can help you. I would recommend you create a code sample only with this code and run it in non-headless mode to see why the element is not appearing.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf, I think that `await page.click("button.green");` is not happening. If I click on that button manually it works, could there be any reason that `page.click()` cannot successfully click? In production, clicking that button no longer works because its connected to `sendgrid` which the free trial has expired, but I am running these tests in development obviously, but wondering if there is a connection somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that the click does not go through for some reason. But impossible to say for sure without seeing the page itself.